# Unable to create new units, but AI is creating new units in StarCraft 1: Brood War

Tags: starcraft

So I am playing an 8-player large custom map created in Campaign Editor. I am Terran, and the other AI players are random.

I, so far, did 56/72 units and have about 20 buildings. I can no longer create any new units or buildings. I get the error: "Cannot create new units."

I removed the fog of war... and I see the AI players are able to create new buildings and units.

Any idea why?

Comment: who made the custom map? Might be a joke of the creator.

Comment: Is there a guide? How do I modify it?

Comment: Sorry I made a edit in my question... The map is created in campaign editor. I didn't see any settings to change the units...

Comment: Old Starcraft does have a limit to how many "units" including buildings and random animals can be on a map at a time. But seeing your enemy can still make them... that should only be possible if something else dies first.

Comment: That I agree with you 100%! I am guessing I may have missed something.... Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The official error should be:

> Cannot create more units.

See screenshot
[image]

This indicates that the map has hit the "Map Max" of 1700 units, buildings, [doodads](http://www.staredit.net/wiki/index.php?title=Doodad), animals, and some spells. This is really hard to do on anything other than "money maps".

I assume the opponent units which you see are coming from Zerg larvae. Larvae is a unit which gets traded into a new unit instantaneously; however, new larvae should not be getting produced. Ditto for drone -> building.

Sources:

- http://www.staredit.net/wiki/index.php/Map_Max
- https://starcraft.fandom.com/wiki/Map_max

Comment: Thank you! Is this limit for all players as a whole OR as a player? It seems I was terrans and I couldn't build anymore but other Terrans and Zergs were building....

Comment: @Si8 It's the map limit, period. No player should be able to produce new units nor buildings unless something gets killed. It's been a number of years since I've played OG StarCraft so I do not remember if a special provision exists for CPU players. The fact that you were only at 56/72 units is ***really*** suspicious; maybe you encountered a one-off bug. Were you turtling with mass turrets? What map were you playing exactly? Were you playing OG StarCraft or remastered? Can you repeat the issue and provide a screenshot after using "black sheep wall"?

Comment: @Si8 Any luck reproducing the issue?

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to get back in the game but I am going to try it. I did play another round where I was a Zerg and although I did get a "cannot create more units" in the beginning of the game... I was able to complete all 200 units! Although two of the races were destroyed in the beginning of the game.

Comment: @Si8 Very strange, sounds like a poorly built map.

Comment: Isn't to build a map just place the spawn points and add minerals and gas.....